# How to use Synchronized Lyrics for MP3 Files using ID3 Tags VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, mp3, id3

I want to know, as the question suggests how to use synced lyrics retrieved using ID3 Tags. I can get the position in milliseconds and the lyrics, as well as a combination of the two. However, I can't figure out how to use them in conjunction with a Media Player. I want that the lyrics appear as and when the media reaches that part.

How would I do this?

Comment: oh i forgot to mention, i use UltraID3LIB. However, if you want to/can do the above work using some other library or your own way, there's no problem.

Comment: Jus a suggestion: UltraID3Lib is a buggy and predecated 3rd party library, you should use TagLibSharp to prevent any kind of "errors".